# How to get first object inside object in angular 8

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a json,I need to just get first object,in this case {"test": {"id":1, "name":"cat"}} from the given object. Here the object is like this
{ "3": {"test": {"id":1, "name":"cat"}},"4": {"test": {"id":2, "name":"dog"}}}. always it may not start from "3" it can start from "0" also. Here is the code below

### app.component.html

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  data:any;
   ngOnInit() {
  this.data = { "3": {"test": {"id":1, "name":"cat"}},
  "4": {"test": {"id":2, "name":"dog"}}};
  console.log(this.data);
}
}
```

Comment: Are there any criteria or you just need the first element from that data NO MATTER WHAT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
data: any;
ngOnInit() {
    this.data = { '3': { test: { id: 1, name: 'cat' } }, '4': { test: { id: 2, name: 'dog' } } };
    console.log(this.data);
    const firstValue = Object.values(this.data)[0];
    console.log(firstValue);
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Html File
    <div *ngFor="let name of values">
    <hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
    </div>

    TS File:
    export class AppComponent  {
      name = 'Angular';
      data: any;
    values:any=[];
      ngOnInit() {
        this.data = { 
          "3": {
            "test": {
              "id":1, 
              "name":"cat"
            }
          },
          "4": {
            "test": {
              "id":2, 
              "name":"dog"
            }
          }
        };

          this.values = Object.keys(this.data).map(key => this.data[key].test.name);

      }
    }
```